# Javascript for checking if the form input quantity exceeds the available quantity in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to check whether the text box input quantity exceeds the available quantity which is in purchase_items table in database. (I am using php for the coding.)

### Code snippet of sales.php

```
function check_qty() {
 var qty=document.getElementById('txtQuantity').value;
 <<code for retrieving "avail_qty" from "purchase_items" table>>
 if(qty>avail_qty) {
     alert("Quantity exceeds.");
    } 
}

<input name="txtQuantity" type="text" id="txtQuantity" size="5" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Only numbers are allowed."/>

<button type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" onclick="check_qty();">ADD</button></td>
```